# NGINX - Enabling/Disabling Location Directive Based on Build Argument

Tags: docker, nginx

I am currently trying to build an NGINX Docker container that will be running alongside a Jupyter container. Within Jupyter, there is a download capability that I wish to disable or enable during the NGINX container build process.

Currently, I am passing a build argument in through the Dockerfile that will be read into the nginx.conf file as an environment variable. However, it seems as though the location directive that controls download within Jupyter cannot be placed within a conditional. If I understand correctly, the location directive must be under the server directive at all times.

```
env DOWNLOAD;

...

http {
   ...
   server {
       ...
       if (DOWNLOAD = 'true') {
           location / {
               ...
           }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to build the container with the configuration above, I run into this error:

```
"location" directive is not allowed here..."
```

My question is - if conditionals are tricky to have functioning correctly in a NGINX conf file, are there are any approaches to controlling a location directive within the NGINX conf file provided an environment variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use:

1. Create nginx-entry.sh file which would resolve all configuration variables of nginx
2. Inject this nginx-entry.sh file into nginx container
3. Switch entrypoint of this nginx container to nginx-entry.sh file

Working sample in my toy project:

- Dockerfile - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-vue/blob/master/Dockerfile
- Nginx config - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-vue/tree/master/nginx

Using this technique you can tweak / template configuration the way you need it.

Comment: This is a fine answer in principle, but it's not an answer to the stated question - which is regarding enabling or disabling an entire block based on a variable. Unless I'm missing something, your way of templating nginx.conf involves simple variable substitution, which isn't sufficient to implement the requested functionality.